# How to mock nextjs useRouter hook with vitest

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vitest

I'm trying to test the call of `useRouter.push` function from my custom hook with Vitest. The issue I'm facing is that I'm not be able to mock the useRouter hook. My goal is to know the `push()` function of `useRouter` was called successfully.

I tried to mock the useRouter hook is this way

```
vi.mock('next/router', () => ({
  useRouter: vi.fn( ()=> {
    return ({
      route: '/',
      pathname: '/',
      query: '',
      asPath: '',
      push: vi.fn(),
      events: {
        on: vi.fn(),
        off: vi.fn()
      },
      beforePopState: vi.fn(() => null),
      prefetch: vi.fn(() => null)
    });
  }),
}));
```

but still I cant check if `useRouter.push` is called on my customHook